# Create a new randomised array out of an existing array, without changing the original

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array -

```
$array = array(
    0 => "a",
    1 => "b",
    2 => "c"
);
```

and I'd like to get a new array out of this one:

```
$new_randomized_array = array(
    0 => "c",
    1 => "a",
    2 => "b"
);
```

using `shuffle($array)` will change the original array, which I do not want.

I could use:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($array, 3);
foreach($rand_keys as $k => $v) {
    $new_randomized_array[] = $array[$v];
}
```

But isn't this redundant?
I'd guess php already has a similar function, but I can't find it.

Comment: You could just shuffle a copy of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, arrays are value types. Thus, you first assign the new array, and then shuffle the new array. Or you can do it through a function call (which also is by-value.)

```
function shuffled_array($a) {
  shuffle($a);
  return $a;
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = shuffled_array($a);
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
```